# Calling ASP.NET Core Web API from another API using HttpClient and Windows auth generating 401 unauthorized error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, httpclient

We have two ASP.NET Core 7.0 Web API services running on the same server. Both are running under different AD service accounts using Windows authentication.

We are making a call from the first service to the second one using `HttpClient`. It works fine while testing locally in my development box. It passes my Windows identity from the first to the second service in the `HttpClient` call and gets authorized, and everything works fine.

After deployment to the server, it gets an http 401 error on the `HttpClient` call from the first to the second service.

Controller code that's getting the 401

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]    
public class WeatherController : Controller
{
```

Program.cs

```
 builder.Services.AddControllers();
 builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
 builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                 .AddNegotiate();

 builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
        });
 builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

 var app = builder.Build();
```

HttpClient call:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl + "Weather/GetWeather").Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        weatherResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Weather>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
    else
    {                   
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"failed: {response.StatusCode}");
    }
}
```

If you look at the IIS log below one shows user account passed which is from development box calling service from Visual Studio the other one is from deployed service where the user account is empty and getting a 401.

> 2023-08-04 21:53:44 xxx.xx.x.xxx GET
> /Weather/GetWeather/5afd17a9-5845-4e23-82e1-153a1927d047/2022-01-01T00:00:00/2023-08-04T17:53:24 - 443 - xxx.xx.x.xxx - - 401 2 5 0
>
> 2023-08-04 21:53:45 xxx.xx.x.xxx GET
> /Weather/GetWeather/5afd17a9-5845-4e23-82e1-153a1927d047/2022-01-01T00:00:00/2023-08-04T17:53:24 - 443 Domain\User xxx.xx.x.xxx - - 200 0 0 1427

Only difference I can see is from development box I am logged into the box under my credentials and VS runs under my account whereas in deployed version, services runs under AD account. Not sure whether I should do something different for passing the Windows identity / credential while calling second service using `HttpClient` (or) are we missing some IIS settings for auth.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One case the account is in the Group "Domain\User" and the other is not.

Comment: Does he same user available in your hosted server as well? In addition, whats your server and IIS version? Is in local machinne or VM or VPC?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron It's Windows Server 2022 Standard , IIS 10 running on a VM.  Locally, during development, Visual Studio is running under my user account, which I used to login to my workstation Services/API run locally under IISExpress. In a hosted environment, it's running under another AD account. Both are part of the domain users. Also we noticed Loaduserprofiles was set to NO in IIS so we are changing it now to see whether it will make a difference. Also plannign to try webclient instead of httpclient as suggested by multiple users. Thanks

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Also planning to try handler.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; instead of usedefaultcredentials.

Comment: Loaduserprofile ON withhandler.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after spending hours and hours trying different ways to access the service in the code, we were able to figure out the issue. It was not the code.

It was loopback authentication enabled on the site or server, Our services were running on the same server/IIS. After disabling loopback authentication, everything worked fine

https://www.codewrecks.com/post/old/2018/09/the-dreadful-iis-loopback-check/